# How do I send the ckeditor config using jQuery service?

Tags: jquery, service, ckeditor, config

My service is built and it is sending the config variable to my js file:
[['SpellChecker','-','Undo','Redo','-','Bold','Italic','Underline','NumberedList','BulletedList']]

The above is assigned to my javascript like so:

```
var config = "<?= stripslashes($_REQUEST['config']) ?>";
```

I can alert out the config just fine:
`console.log(config)` does send back the correct data...

However, I get an error thrown in my console!:

> v is undefined [Break On This Error]
>   var
>   u=n.toolbox.toolbars,v=n.config.to...aximize','ShowBlocks','-','About']];

If I comment out the config:

//CKEDITOR.config.toolbar = config;

everything works fine but the configuration doesn't exist, of course...

Answer (score 0):

FIXED...PFFFFFFFFT

```
// Setup the configurations for this instance
CKEDITOR.config.toolbar = eval(config);
```

Comment: try without the initial quotes: var config = <?= stripslashes($_REQUEST['config']) ?>;

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> $(document).ready(function(){
>     $('.reply').click(
>     function(event){
>         // Event click Off Default
>         event.preventDefault();
>         // CKEditor
>         $(function(){
>             var config = {toolbar:[['Bold', 'Italic', '-', 'Link', 'Unlink']]};
>             //<?php /*echo"var config = {toolbar:[['Bold', 'Italic', '-', 'Link', 'Unlink']]};" ;*/ ?>
>             // DOM class = "cke"
>             $('textarea.cke').ckeditor(function(){}, config);                
>         });
>         return false;
>     });
> });
> ```